# Swift: Subview Listens for Parent to call viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, listener, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have a custom collection view whose cell sizes are determined by the view controller. Because the layout is set before the cell size (cell size is set in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`), the layout does not work correctly unless it is set inside of the view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Is there a way to have the custom collection view listen for when the view controller calls `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? I want to keep as much as possible inside of the custom collection view.

Thank you in advance!